# Phoenix routes not 404ing in production only

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am having an issue where some where a set of routes is unavailable in production for an unknwown reason.  I have

```
  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html", "json"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :auth do
    plug GroundedWarrior.Auth.AuthAccessPipeline
  end
```

for pipelines and

```
 scope "/admin", GroundedWarriorWeb do
   pipe_through :browser

   get "/login", AdminSessionController, :new, as: :admin_login
   post "/login", AdminSessionController, :create, as: :admin_session
 end

 scope "/admin", GroundedWarriorWeb do
  pipe_through([:browser, :auth])

  get "/", AdminController, :index
 end
```

for routes, the login routes work, but the ones that include `auth` pipeline just 404 in production, has anyone experienced something similar?

SOLVED:

Ended up being that i needed to have my auth checks distinguish between admins and non-admins, it was trying to find a non-admin with id 1 (the admins id from the token) and no finding, resulting in a 404 being thrown

Comment: Can you show us the `GroundedWarrior.Auth.AuthAccessPipeline` module? Is it possible that you are sending a 404 from there?

Comment: @JustinWood, yes I solved thats what it ended up being, it was 404 finding the user in the wrong store, it was just strange that it caused the route to 404 that way.